# Unable to setup KIE workbench and KIE server 7.35 on Wildfly 14

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench, wildfly-14

I managed to deploy KIE workbench and server 6.4.0 on wildfly 8.2.1.
but
When trying to deploy version 7.35.0 on wildfly 14.0 it fails with the following error :

> "WFLYDS0022: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation
>   within the allowed timeout period [600 seconds]. Check the server
>   configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status
>   of the deployment."

I am using standalone-full.xml while deployment.

Comment: Perhaps, you can add more configurations you make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is happening due to some services are taking long time than usual to start and due to it server is not able to start within the default timeout.

You can change default timeout using below property and see if that works for you.

```
<system-propeties>
  <property name="jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout" value="1000"/>
<system-propeties>
```

Also, you can try by disabling the deployment scanner.

```
/subsystem=deployment-scanner/scanner=default:write-attribute(name=scan-enabled,value=false)
```